# Commutating operators modulo compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators, unbounded-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space. I want find an example of a closed densely defined operator $A$ and a bounded operator $B$ such that $AB - BA = K$ where $K$ is a compact operator.